# Little's missing completely at random (MCAR) test error

Tags: r, missing-data

I want to perform Little's MCAR Test to evaluate missing data pattern with a dataset of 34 Variables (metric, ordinal, nominal) and 71 observations.

I get the following error applying little MCAR test in R with Naniar package:

```
mcar_test(myData)

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `d2`.
i `d2 = purrr::pmap_dbl(...)`.
x system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.55842e-25
i The error occurred in group 1: miss_pattern = 1.

> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` column `d2`.
i `d2 = purrr::pmap_dbl(...)`.
x system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.55842e-25
i The error occurred in group 1: miss_pattern = 1.
Backtrace:
1. naniar::mcar_test(myData)
14. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
15. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` column `d2`.
i `d2 = purrr::pmap_dbl(...)`.
x system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.55842e-25
i The error occurred in group 1: miss_pattern = 1.
Backtrace:
     x
1. +-naniar::mcar_test(myData)
2. | \-`%>%`(...)
3. +-dplyr::ungroup(.)
4. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
5. +-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
6. | \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
7. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
8. |   \-mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
9. +-purrr::pmap_dbl(...)
10. | \-naniar:::.f(...)
11. |   +-base::ifelse(...)
12. |   +-base::solve(..3)
13. |   \-base::solve.default(..3)
14. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
15.   \-dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
<error/simpleError>
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.55842e-25
```

When I exclude one time variable "A" it works.

Here's my code for the relevant Variable:

```
    #packages (tidyverse, broom, robustbase, readxl, ggThemeAssist, knitr, MASS, rmarkdown, devtools, naniar)

    #A (metric variabel, time variabel in hours)
    myData$A <- as.factor(myData$A)
    myData$A[myData$A==-999] <-NA


    > dput(myData[1:10, 2])


structure(list(A = structure(c(36L, 35L, 42L, 
38L, 20L, 17L, 40L, 27L, 44L, 39L), .Label = c("-999", "0.07", 
"0.09", "0.11", "0.16", "0.18", "0.21", "0.22", "0.3", "0.32", 
"0.33", "0.38", "0.39", "0.4", "0.41", "0.43", "0.44", "0.47", 
"0.5", "0.51", "0.55", "0.59", "1", "1.12", "1.13", "1.15", "1.18", 
"1.28", "1.35", "1.37", "1.39", "1.45", "1.49", "1.55", "1.57", 
"2.02", "2.03", "2.24", "2.26", "2.33", "2.41", "3.28", "3.54", 
"6.25", "6.32", "23.3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Why is my matrix singular?

Regards,

M.

Comment: Probably there is an issue with your code. Or maybe your data. Perhaps both? Could you show the relevant code that you are using, including any necessary packages, and provide a small sample of data? `dput()` is the nicest way to share data, e.g. `dput(your_data[1:10, 1:5])` gives a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows and first 5 columns of `your_data`, including all class and structure information.

Comment: I edited this a bit and voted to reopen it, but I'm realizing now there's still detail missing. We don't need all the code that defines your data since you gave us the `dput` of it. What we *do* need is the code that causes the error